# varnish 4.0 block all ip addresses exept for whitelisted

Tags: varnish

We have a load balancer for our varnish servers, and only that should be allowed to send traffic to varnish.

Is there a way to block all ip addresses except for the 2 ip addresses from the load balancer from getting requests from Varnish?

Comment: you might want to consider to do such a thing in your firewall acl rather than at the application level in varnish.

Comment: Unfortunately the firewall team wont let me. I have to block on an application level. Can easily be done in apache but I am fronting apache with varnish